# Laravel custom rule pass array attribute

Tags: laravel

I have a custom rule and not sure how to pass one array attribute to that rule.

Following is my `formRequest` rules method

```
'reservedProducts'             => ['bail', 'array'],
'reservedProducts.*.productId' => ['required',new CheckForStockAvailability()],
```

There is another hidden field passed in array named `reservedProducts[locationId]`, how do I pass that `locationId` to `CheckForStockAvailability` rule?

I do not want to pass all request attributes but instead just pass the `locationId`.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please show an example of the request body?

Answer (score 0):

For example, consider the following rule that specifies that a credit card number is required if the payment_type has a value of cc:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'credit_card_number' => 'required_if:payment_type,cc' ]);
```

If this validation rule fails, it will produce the following error message:

> The credit card number field is required when payment type is cc.

Instead of displaying cc as the payment type value, you may specify a more user-friendly value representation in your resources/lang/xx/validation.php language file by defining a values array:

```
'values' => [
    'payment_type' => [
        'cc' => 'credit card'
    ],
],
```

After defining this value, the validation rule will produce the following error message:

> The credit card number field is required when payment type is credit
> card.

Answer (score 0):

in your `formRequest`

```php
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'reservedProducts' => [
                'bail', 'array'
            ],
            'reservedProducts.*' => [
                'required',
                function($attribute, $value, $fail){
                    var_dump($value); // -> reservedProducts.0 {"productId":2} 

                    preg_match('/reservedProducts.(.*?) {/', $value, $match);
                    $locationId = (int)$match[1]; // -> 0
                }
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: I have not run the code but I guess `$locationId` will still be the same as `productId` in the function. I want to pass `locationId` which is a hidden field in the form to `CheckForStockAvailability` rule.

Comment: @MikeRoss Sorry for my carelessness, it should be `'reservedProducts.*'` instead of `'reservedProducts.*'.productId`